# Fastest way to delete a Collection from Firestore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that loads millions of documents to a collection, using 30-80 workers to simultaneously load the data.  Sometimes, I find that the loading process didn't complete smoothly, and with other databases I can simply delete the table and start over, but not with Firestore collections.  I have to list the documents and delete them, and I've not found a way to scale this with the same capacity as my loading process.  What I'm doing now is that I have two AppEngine hosted Flask/Python methods, one to get a page of 1000 documents and pass to another method to delete them.  This way the process to list documents is not blocked by the process to delete them.  It's still taking days to complete which is too long.

Method to get list of documents and create a task to delete them, which is single threaded:

```
@app.route('/delete_collection/<collection_name>/<batch_size>', methods=['POST'])
def delete_collection(collection_name, batch_size):
    batch_size = int(batch_size)
    coll_ref = db.collection(collection_name)
    print('Received request to delete collection {} {} docs at a time'.format(
        collection_name,
        batch_size
    ))
    num_docs = batch_size
    while num_docs >= batch_size:
        docs = coll_ref.limit(batch_size).stream()
        found = 0
        deletion_request = {
            'doc_ids': []
        }
        for doc in docs:
            deletion_request['doc_ids'].append(doc.id)
            found += 1
        num_docs = found
        print('Creating request to delete docs: {}'.format(
            json.dumps(deletion_request)
        ))
        # Add to task queue
        queue = tasks_client.queue_path(PROJECT_ID, LOCATION, 'database-manager')

        task_meet = {
            'app_engine_http_request': {  # Specify the type of request.
                'http_method': 'POST',
                'relative_uri': '/delete_documents/{}'.format(
                    collection_name
                ),
                'body': json.dumps(deletion_request).encode(),
                'headers': {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        }
        task_response_meet = tasks_client.create_task(queue, task_meet)
        print('Created task to delete {} docs: {}'.format(
            batch_size,
            json.dumps(deletion_request)
        ))
```

Here is the method I use to delete the documents, which can scale.  In effect it only processes 5-10 at a time, limited by the rate which the other method passes pages of doc_ids to delete.  Separating the two helps, but not that much.

```
@app.route('/delete_documents/<collection_name>', methods=['POST'])
def delete_documents(collection_name):
    # Validate we got a body in the POST
    if flask.request.json:
        print('Request received to delete docs from :{}'.format(collection_name))
    else:
        message = 'No json found in request: {}'.format(flask.request)
        print(message)
        return message, 400

    # Validate that the payload includes a list of doc_ids
    doc_ids = flask.request.json.get('doc_ids', None)
    if doc_ids is None:
        return 'No doc_ids specified in payload: {}'.format(flask.request.json), 400
    print('Received request to delete docs: {}'.format(doc_ids))
    for doc_id in doc_ids:
        db.collection(collection_name).document(doc_id).delete()
    return 'Finished'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set environment variables for running locally
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I've tried running multiple concurrent executions of delete_collection(), but am not certain that even helps, as I'm not sure if every time it calls limit(batch_size).stream() that it gets a distinct set of documents or possibly is getting duplicates.

How can I make this run faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with.  It's not super fast (120-150 docs per second), but all the other examples I found in python didn't work at all:

```
now = datetime.now()
then = now - timedelta(days=DOCUMENT_EXPIRATION_DAYS)
doc_counter = 0
commit_counter = 0
limit = 5000
while True:
    docs = []
    print('Getting next doc handler')
    docs = [snapshot for snapshot in db.collection(collection_name)
        .where('id.time', '<=', then)
        .limit(limit)
        .order_by('id.time', direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING
      ).stream()]
    batch = db.batch()
    for doc in docs:
        doc_counter = doc_counter + 1
        if doc_counter % 500 == 0:
            commit_counter += 1
            print('Committing batch {} from {}'.format(commit_counter, doc.to_dict()['id']['time']))
            batch.commit()
        batch.delete(doc.reference)
    batch.commit()
    if len(docs) == limit:
        continue
    break

print('Deleted {} documents in {} seconds.'.format(doc_counter, datetime.now() - now))
```

As mentioned in the other comments, .stream() has a 60 second deadline.  This iterative structure sets a limit of 5000 after which .stream() is called again, which keeps it under the 60 second limit.  If anybody knows how to speed this up, let me know.

Comment: Using similar code, I'm seeing deletion rate of about 350 documents/second. Possible time-saving difference: I am not doing an order_by in the stream() query.

Comment: If you have a suitable property for running this code in parallel, you can make it much faster. Currently using NodeJS instead of Python, and I see deletion rates of nearly 1'000 documents per second. I expect results would be similar with Python. My data is distributed quite evenly on one property, which can take on about 10 values. So I just run this code 10 times, and each execution just works on one of these property values.

Answer (score 4):

I recently face the same challenge when trying to clean up a huge collection in staging environment. You can use Firebase CLI delete command to remove a collection, or even all collection, and for my case, it was able to delete document at about 3000-4000 documents/second.

You can use:

```
firebase firestore:delete ---shallow [collection-name]
```

Or if you want to also delete all documents in subcollections, you can use:

```
firebase firestore:delete ---recursive [collection-name]
```

You could also find more details by checking `firebase firestore:delete --help`. Honestly, it's a bit annoying that this command is not really visible in the documentation, I could only find the reference to this command here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands

Comment: This is the fastest method.

Answer (score 1):

In this [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/delete-collections) is described how using a callable Cloud Function you can take advantage of the firestore delete command in the [Firebase Command Line Interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) deleting up to 4000 documents per second.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, unfortunately the only example is with Node.  Looking for a way to do this with Python.

Comment: It’s not clear from the documentation whether the CLI  can be called from Python. There are no examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple Python script that I used to test batch deletes. Like @Chris32 said, the batch mode will delete thousands of documents per second if latency isn't too bad.

```
from time import time
from uuid import uuid4
from google.cloud import firestore

DB = firestore.Client()

def generate_user_data(entries = 10):
    print('Creating {} documents'.format(entries))
    now = time()
    batch = DB.batch()
    for counter in range(entries):
        # Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents.
        # https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions
        if counter % 500 == 0 and counter > 0:
            batch.commit()

        user_id = str(uuid4())
        data = {
            "some_data": str(uuid4()),
            "expires_at": int(now)
            }
        user_ref = DB.collection(u'users').document(user_id)
        batch.set(user_ref, data)
    batch.commit()
    print('Wrote {} documents in {:.2f} seconds.'.format(entries, time() - now))

def delete_one_by_one():
    print('Deleting documents one by one')
    now = time()
    docs = DB.collection(u'users').where(u'expires_at', u'<=', int(now)).stream()
    counter = 0
    for doc in docs:
        doc.reference.delete()
        counter = counter + 1
    print('Deleted {} documents in {:.2f} seconds.'.format(counter, time() - now))

def delete_in_batch():
    print('Deleting documents in batch')
    now = time()
    docs = DB.collection(u'users').where(u'expires_at', u'<=', int(now)).stream()
    batch = DB.batch()
    counter = 0
    for doc in docs:
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter % 500 == 0:
            batch.commit()
        batch.delete(doc.reference)
    batch.commit()
    print('Deleted {} documents in {:.2f} seconds.'.format(counter, time() - now))


generate_user_data(10)
delete_one_by_one()
print('###')
generate_user_data(10)
delete_in_batch()
print('###')
generate_user_data(2000)
delete_in_batch()
```

Comment: Do you not get a bunch of deadline errors after 15-20 batches?  This is working for me but I need to retry often before it gets through all the docs.